# How can i insert,update,delete JSON objects using ios(Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am Fetch JSON data using `NSURLSession` Class. but, I am unable to insert,update,delete JSON Objects runtime. Please any one guide me with suitable example and flow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to update, exactly?  In memory data-structure?  Database?  Server?  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Avi, i am trying to modify server side objects which we fetch through JSON. please assist me.  Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Realm](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON) and JSON.. or save JSON strings to file like this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory

NSError *error;
BOOL succeed = [myJSONObject writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"object-id.json"]
      atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (!succeed){
    // Handle error here
}
```